# local_action copy content file format

Tags: ansible

I have a playbook output show commands and I'm trying to get it to send the output to a file in human readable format.

here is my code:

```
- name: Run a set of commands
      junos_command:
        commands: [ 'show route summary', 'show bgp sum' ]
        output: text 
        provider: "{{ netconf }}"
      register: showcmds

- name: copy content
  local_action: copy content={{ showcmds }} dest=backups/{{ show_file }}

- name: display show commands
  debug: var=showcmds.stdout_lines
```

But the file looks like this:

```
[gary.rubel@sl7jump2 backups]$ more car1.txt
{"failed": false, "changed": false, "stdout": ["Autonomous system number: 3561\nRouter ID: 90.90.90.70\n\ninet.0: 1
1 destinations, 11 routes (11 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)\nLimit/Threshold: 16384/16384 destinations\n           
   Direct:      2 routes,      2 active\n               Local:      5 routes,      5 active\n              Static: 
     3 routes,      3 active\n                IGMP:      1 routes,      1 active\n\ncoin-a.inet.0: 106 destinations
, 202 routes (106 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)\n              Direct:      5 routes,      5 active\n              
 Local:      8 routes,      8 active\n                 BGP:    173 routes,     77 active\n               IS-IS:    
 13 routes,     13 active\n                IGMP:      1 routes,      1 active\n                 PIM:      2 routes,
      2 active\n\ncoin-a.inet.1: 43 destinations, 43 routes (43 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)\n           Multicast
:     43 routes,     43 active\n\niso.0: 1 destinations, 1 routes (1 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)\n              D
irect:      1 routes,      1 active\n\ncoin-a.iso.0: 1 destinations, 1 routes (1 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)\n   
           Direct:      1 routes,      1 active\n\ncoin-a.inet6.0: 2 destinations, 2 routes (2 active, 0 holddown, 
0 hidden)\n                 PIM:      2 routes,      2 active\n\ncoin-a.inet6.1: 1 destinations, 1 routes (1 active
, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)\n           Multicast:      1 routes,      1 active", "Groups: 5 Peers: 6 Down peers: 4\nPe
er                     AS      InPkt     OutPkt    OutQ   Flaps Last Up/Dwn State|#Active/Received/Accepted/Damped.
..\n10.191.254.241        55061          0          0       0       0      3w5d6h Idle  \n166.49.31.54           79
86          0          0       0       0      3w5d6h Idle  \n172.16.30.30           3561      32013      31956     
  0      31  3d 8:14:02 Establ\n  coin-a.inet.0: 66/82/82/0\n172.16.50.50           3561     240667     251117     
  0       0      3w5d6h Establ\n  coin-a.inet.0: 11/91/91/0\n172.16.51.51          64800          0          0     
  0       0      3w5d6h Active\n198.168.10.2           7986          0          0       0       0      3w5d6h Idle"
], "stdout_lines": [["Autonomous system number: 3561", "Router ID: 90.90.90.70", "", "inet.0: 11 destinations, 11 r
outes (11 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)", "Limit/Threshold: 16384/16384 destinations", "              Direct:      
2 routes,      2 active", "               Local:      5 routes,      5 active", "              Static:      3 route
s,      3 active", "                IGMP:      1 routes,      1 active", "", "coin-a.inet.0: 106 destinations, 202 
routes (106 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)", "              Direct:      5 routes,      5 active", "               L
ocal:      8 routes,      8 active", "                 BGP:    173 routes,     77 active", "               IS-IS:  
   13 routes,     13 active", "                IGMP:      1 routes,      1 active", "                 PIM:      2 r
outes,      2 active", "", "coin-a.inet.1: 43 destinations, 43 routes (43 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)", "        
   Multicast:     43 routes,     43 active", "", "iso.0: 1 destinations, 1 routes (1 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)"
, "              Direct:      1 routes,      1 active", "", "coin-a.iso.0: 1 destinations, 1 routes (1 active, 0 ho
lddown, 0 hidden)", "              Direct:      1 routes,      1 active", "", "coin-a.inet6.0: 2 destinations, 2 ro
utes (2 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)", "                 PIM:      2 routes,      2 active", "", "coin-a.inet6.1: 
1 destinations, 1 routes (1 active, 0 holddown, 0 hidden)", "           Multicast:      1 routes,      1 active"], 
["Groups: 5 Peers: 6 Down peers: 4", "Peer                     AS      InPkt     OutPkt    OutQ   Flaps Last Up/Dwn
State|#Active/Received/Accepted/Damped...", "10.191.254.241        55061          0          0       0       0    
  3w5d6h Idle  ", "166.49.31.54           7986          0          0       0       0      3w5d6h Idle  ", "172.16.3
0.30           3561      32013      31956       0      31  3d 8:14:02 Establ", "  coin-a.inet.0: 66/82/82/0", "172.
16.50.50           3561     240667     251117       0       0      3w5d6h Establ", "  coin-a.inet.0: 11/91/91/0", "
172.16.51.51          64800          0          0       0       0      3w5d6h Active", "198.168.10.2           7986
          0          0       0       0      3w5d6h Idle"]]}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried simply pushing the "stdout_lines" directly to the file? I see you are spitting those as a debug but not into the file. Usually that's the way to go if you want the line breakers to be interpreted. (while stdout is for string output)

```
- name: copy content
  local_action: copy content={{ showcmds.stdout_lines }} dest=backups/{{ show_file }}
```

In case I'm misreading this and you actually want to send the entire output in a "prettier" way, you can consider the registered variable a dictionary and send the output line by line.

```
- name: copy content
  local_action: lineinfile line={{ item }} path=backups/{{ show_file }}
  with_dict: {{ showcmds }}
```

I hope this helps. :)

Comment: Tried the above and output wasn't working: /* Found another way */

Answer (score 0):

Try setting output to "json" in your first task, so it would look like this: `output: json`.

A helpful tool I use when working with json is the "prettyjson" package. You will need Node to install it.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/prettyjson

https://nodejs.org/en/download/

And then you can run the following commands:

`prettyjson car1.json`

`more car1.json | prettyjson`

Hope this helps!

Comment: - name: Run a set of commands  
      junos_command:  
        commands: [ 'show route summary', 'show bgp sum' ]  
        output: text   
        provider: "{{ netconf }}"
      register: showcmds

    - set_fact:  
        readout: "{{ showcmds.stdout_lines | to_nice_yaml }}"  
     
    - name: copy content  
      local_action:   
        copy content="{{ readout }}"  
        dest="{{ report_dir }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"

Comment: - name: Run a set of commands
      junos_command:
        commands: [ 'show route summary', 'show bgp sum' ]
        output: text 
        provider: "{{ netconf }}"
      register: showcmds

    - set_fact:
        readout: "{{ showcmds.stdout_lines | to_nice_yaml }}"
     
    - name: copy content
      local_action: 
        copy content="{{ readout }}"
        dest="{{ report_dir }}/{{ inventory_hostname }}.txt"

Comment: @GaryRubel - What?